# Disabling Outlook calendar reminder programmatically in C# when creating Outlook appointment

Tags: c#, outlook

I am trying to figure out disabling Outlook reminder programmatically in C#  when creating Outlook appointment and I tried Appointment properties but nothing seems to be working. Are there ways to accomplish this?

```
    TimeZoneInfo easternTZ = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2016, easternTZ);

    service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(WEB_CRDENTIALS_ID, WEB_CRDENTIALS_PW, "xyz");
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;              
    service.Url = new Uri(EWS_URL);               
    Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service);
    appointment.Subject = "Appointment with xxxxx";
....
....
    appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);                              
    appointment.IsReminderSet = false;
    appointment.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = -1;           

    Item item = Item.Bind(service, appointment.Id, new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Subject));
```

thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Does the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.reminder?view=outlook-pia) help?

Comment: Also, please [edit] in any attempt you performed to your question please.  That way, we can change/adjust your code more exactly to fit your needs and give you a better answer.

Comment: @gravity I added my code. I took a look the documentation. Should I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem instead of Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment?